# Wildfire: Cleanup without irritating moderators

Tags: app, flags

### About

Moderators don't like seeing a whole horde of flags in their precious flag queue. They dislike this even more when all the flags are from one user who is obviously running a search or query and flagging everything.

However, this bad content shouldn't be ignored.

This app (if it ends up actually existing) will allow you to 'queue up' flags, for dispensing at a sane pace. The flags will come from your account, not mine. This does mean I (or whoever hosts this) would theoretically be able to perform actions on your behalf. Weigh those risks... or just host it yourself.

Also, to combat the effects of something happening to a post that would make your previously valid flag invalid, we'll check the last activity date on the post.

#### License

[CC0](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/Wildfire/blob/master/LICENSE)

#### Download

Available at http://wildfire.erwaysoftware.com, but accounts currently require manual authorization before they become active.

#### Platform

Anything with a semi-modern browser. IE folks: no guarantees.

### Contact

I made this.

### Code

Get everything [on GitHub](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/flag-eventually), it's written on RoR.

Comment: Do we need to ping you here to get approval, or what?

Comment: @NathanTuggy That's probably the best thing to do, I've approved your account there. Just... please don't abuse it, my reason for locking it down in the first place is to avoid people going nuts and flagging things from a query without reviewing them, etc. :)

Comment: Thanks. I actually plan to use it mostly for the secondary feature of shutting off flags if there's been an edit.